# Terraform: How to supply attributes of resources which where created using one resource block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can I supply multiple values to the `subnet_ids` attribute as below?

```
resource "aws_subnet" "db_subnet" {
  for_each = var.db_subnet_cidrs

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = each.value
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "default-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = ["aws_subnet.db_subnet.*.id"]

  tags = {
    Name = "database-subnet-group"
  }
}
```

The subnets are being created correctly but the subnet group isn't. When I `apply` this I get the following error:

```
Error: Error creating DB Subnet Group: InvalidParameterValue: Some input subnets in :[aws_subnet.db_subnet.*.id] are invalid.
        status code: 400, request id: 0b68518f-e229-4f57-bf68-4ba46c1c75c2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is trying to set the subnet IDs of the DB subnet group equal to a string literal of `aws_subnet.db_subnet.*.id` which is obviously not a valid subnet identifier. Normally Terraform would warn you that it doesn't match a subnet ID format (eg `subnet-1234abcd`) but it looks like the [`aws_db_subnet_group` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_subnet_group.html) [doesn't currently validate this](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/f61b73d3976a2f9d1afe77d43f604b2f2f25a063/aws/resource_aws_db_subnet_group.go#L56-L61).

Secondly, the way you're trying to use the output of a `for_each` looped resource also won't work. If you were using `count` to loop over your subnets that you are creating then you'd have something like the following:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "db_subnet" {
  count = length(var.db_subnet_cidrs)

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id
  availability_zone = count.index
  cidr_block        = var.db_subnet_cidrs[count.index]
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "default-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.db_subnet.*.id

  tags = {
    Name = "database-subnet-group"
  }
}
```

The `count` looped resources have a [splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) output that has all of the outputs as a list already so you can pass that directly to the `aws_db_subnet_group` resource.

But if you want to use `for_each` to loop over things then you currently need to use a slightly different syntax to get at the values from the looped resource:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "db_subnet" {
  for_each = var.db_subnet_cidrs

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = each.value
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "default-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = values(aws_subnet.db_subnet)[*].id

  tags = {
    Name = "database-subnet-group"
  }
}
```

This will extract the values of the looped `aws_subnet` resource, grabs all of them and then uses just the `id` attribute from the resource. The use of the splat operator again creates a list that you can pass directly to the `subnet_ids` parameter in the `aws_db_subnet` resource.

Answer (score 0):

I was also encountering the same error. my architecture design included a single VPC with 2 subnets. These 2 subnets were in same availability zone`[us-east-1a]`.
to overcome the aforementioned error, I simply changed the AZs of and subnets`[us-east-1a][us-east-1b]` and BOOM!
**It worked**